# if and else if do the same thing

Tags: if-statement, refactoring, logic

I'm trying to refactor an if-else chain that doesn't look particularly good. My common sense is telling me that I should be able to call my method only once but I can't figure out an elegant way to do it. Currently what I have is:

```
if(condition1)
  do method1;
else if(condition2)
  do method1;
```

Which looks hideous. There's repeat code! The best I can come up with is:

```
if(condition1 || (!condition1 && condition2))
  do method1;
```

But this also looks bad, since I'm negating `condition1` after the or, which seems unnecessary...

I made a truth table for this:

```
 c1| c2| r
 0 | 0 | 0
 0 | 1 | 1
 1 | 0 | 1
 1 | 1 | 1
```

And in case anyone is interested, the real-life problem I'm having is that I got 2 intances of Fancytree in javascript and I want to set some rules to transferring nodes between them. Tree A can only transfer lone nodes to Tree B, while Tree B can reorder itself freely, so I put this on Tree B's `dragDrop` event:

```
if(data.otherNode.tree === node.tree){ 
  data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
}
else if(!data.otherNode.hasChildren()){
  data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);              
}
```

Comment: Is there a point in negating first condition in second code? If condition1 gives true it won't go to condition2, if it returns false it'll go to check condition2.

Comment: What you have in the first code snippet is a simple `OR`.

Comment: Truth table seems wrong to me: can you check?

Comment: It isn't. I need to negate condition1 on the `OR`. If I don't then (referring to the javascript code in the end) I won't allow movement of Tree B nodes that have children.

Comment: @MarkLeiber For the record, this is example code which would be off-topic on CR.

Comment: Your truth table is wrong. For your truth table it would be !condition1 || condition2 but that isn't how you wrote your code above.

Comment: You guys are right, the truth table was wrong. I apologize. I corrected it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify even more - if the first condition is `true`, the method should be invoked **regardless of the second condition**. So the `!condition1` in your refactored code is redundant. Instead, you could just have:

```
if(condition1 || condition2)
  do method1;
```

In modern programming languages the if condition will even short circuit. This means that when the first condition is evaluated as `true`, the second condition won't even get evaluated.

Comment: You're right. I feel like I was freaking out about nothing and wasted everyone's time. I feel very dumb. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggested,

```
if(condition1 || (!condition1 && condition2))
  do method1;
```

Is logically the same as

```
if(condition1 || condition2)
  do method1;
```

So I think that is your best answer.

It's not logically the same as your truth table though, so either your truth table or your current code is wrong, if truth table r is meant to do 
`do method1;`

Answer (score 1):

In writing

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
    //code1
}
```

if condition1 is correct code1 is executed and if condition1 is incorrect then only condition2 is checked and code proceeds accordingly. Hence it would be same as

```
if ( condition1 ) {
    //method1
} else if ( condition2 ) {
    //method1
}
```